# Scala Spark RDDs, DataSet, PairRDDs and Partitoning

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd, apache-spark-dataset

In Scala Spark, there are several methods that can result into data partitioning/repartitioning.  These include `partitionBy, coalesce, repartition, and textFile` among other functions that have a partition-count as parameter. Below, I use `textFile` with a specification of at least 8 partitions. I do not want transformations to undo these partitions. For partitions to be preserved, you need to `persist` the partitioning result. However, functions such as `map` and `flatMap` do not preserve the partitions. This I believe can be a hit on performance. PairRDDS have `mapValues and flatMapValues` that maintain partitions.

Are there equivalent functions for `DataSets and RDDs` for `map and flatMap` that do not screw up partitions?

If I have this all mixed up, how do RDDs and DataSets maintain there partitions putting in mind that map and flatMap operations are key in their manipulation.

```
val tweets:RDD[Tweet] = mySpark.sparkContext.textFile(path,8).map(parseTweet).persist()
val numerical_fields_Tweets:Dataset[Tweet] = tweets.toDS()
```

[image: Below is a screenshot from a youtube video stating that a map in a pairRDD results in an RDD without a partitioner]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Spark, operations that do not repartition/shuffle the data preserve partitions (by operating on the previously established partitions). `map` and `flatMap` are such operations: they will not alter the number of partitions. Further, `map` will not change the number of rows within partitions or their order.

> how do RDDs and DataSets maintain there partitions

You are mixing two concepts: (1) the partitioner associated with data at a point in its transformation and (2) the partitions the data is split into.

There is a difference between how data is partitioned vs. which partitioner is associated with the data. As explained above, `map` and `flatMap` do not change the number of partitions but they make no guarantees about the partitioner associated with the data. Consider RDD's `map`:

```
/**
 * Return a new RDD by applying a function to all elements of this RDD.
 */
def map[U: ClassTag](f: T => U): RDD[U] = withScope {
  val cleanF = sc.clean(f)
  new MapPartitionsRDD[U, T](this, (context, pid, iter) => iter.map(cleanF))
}
```

and `MapPartitionsRDD`:

```
private[spark] class MapPartitionsRDD[U: ClassTag, T: ClassTag](
    var prev: RDD[T],
    f: (TaskContext, Int, Iterator[T]) => Iterator[U],
    preservesPartitioning: Boolean = false, ...)
```

So, while `map` doesn't repartition the data, it makes no guarantees about the partitioner associated with the data because there are no restrictions on how `map` may modify rows.

Pair RDDs, i.e., `RDD[(K, V)]`, are somewhat special in that they are often the result of a partitioning operation and, if we use `mapValues` instead of `map`, we can be certain that the partitioner has not changed because we have not touched the "keys".

```
/**
 * Pass each value in the key-value pair RDD through a map function without changing the keys;
 * this also retains the original RDD's partitioning.
 */
def mapValues[U](f: V => U): RDD[(K, U)] = self.withScope {
  val cleanF = self.context.clean(f)
  new MapPartitionsRDD[(K, U), (K, V)](self,
    (context, pid, iter) => iter.map { case (k, v) => (k, cleanF(v)) },
    preservesPartitioning = true)
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: A map for a pairRDD results into an RDD without a partitioner. What does that mean?

Comment: What is the source of this statement? Can you provide a link?

Comment: See the attached screenshot from a youtube Tutorial

Comment: I have two questions. 1. It appears most articles talk about keys when it comes to partitioning. Does that mean partitioning only applies to pairRDD? 2. If I perform a partitioning then do perform an action such as reduce/fold, does it mean that the partitioning is undone and I will have to do a repartition after the action for better performance?